# Create both, trusty and xenial packages in Ubuntu PPA

Tags: package-management, ppa, launchpad

I am creating package with debuild -S. Then I upload with dput ppa:user/ppaname packagename_source.changes.

My package is correctly builded and published. But, only deb files for trusty are created. Well, my computer is still trusty but I would like to publish packages also for xenial and newer systems. Ideally, I would like that my ppa includes packages for trusty and xenial. How can I make this?

https://launchpad.net/~meolic/+archive/ubuntu/biddy

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Copy the source to another directory and edit the `debian/changelog` file in your source and replace `trusty` with `xenial` in the first line.

Also note that Launchpad will not accept packages with identical versions even if they are intended for different releases.

So replace the version there too, e.g. append `~xenial` to it. It does not really matter what you append there, but you must change it somehow.

It will look this way:

```
libbiddy1 (1.6-1~xenial) xenial; urgency=medium
```

Then do `debuild -S` again and upload.